# Adding additional attributes to Rails has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models, `MainAccount` and `Account`, both associated with a `has_and_belongs_to_many` record, which looks like this:

```
class MainAccount < ApplicationRecord
  # associations
  has_and_belongs_to_many :accounts
end
```

and

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :main_accounts
end
```

I ran the following to generate the migration file:

```
rails g migration CreationJoinTableAccountsMainAccounts main_accounts accounts
```

I also added an attribute called `connected` as a `booelan`. It looks like this:

```
class CreationJoinTableAccountsMainAccounts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_join_table :main_accounts, :accounts do |t|
      t.boolean :connected

      t.index %i[main_account_id account_id]
      t.index %i[account_id main_account_id]
    end
  end
end
```

I'm able to create an account from the main account, but I have no idea how to insert the `connected: true` into the equation.

I have tried the following:

```
MainAccount.first.accounts.create(username: "hello")
```

but that just creates an `Account` record with the `username: "hello"`. If I try to add `connected: true`, it says that `connected` doesn't exist on the `Account` model, which it doesn't.

In this particular scenario, I have many accounts and accounts, some which link together and some don't. I also have other attributes that I need to add.

Any suggestions on creating additional associations without duplicating `Account` and `MainAccount` records by accident in the process? For example if I have two `MainAccount` records and need to link both to one `Account`, but one needs to have `connected: true` and the other needs to have `connected: false`, how would I accomplish this?

Am I going about it the wrong way perhaps? Essentially, I need a joins table but I also need to connect other attributes to the associated record

Comment: Can you please share the schema file after the migration is run?

Answer (score 2):

Usually, a `has_and_belongs_to_many` table only has two attributes (excluding the default timestamps), each of them having the `id` of the corresponding association (in your case: **`account_id`** and **`main_account_id`**). You'll need a `has_many through` relationship to add the `connected` attribute into the equation. A `has_many through` relationship basically sets up a many-to-many connection with another model.

The `connected` attribute should be in the `AccountConnection` model. (By the way, this could be any name you want - just using I could think now as a example, but it can and should be what best describes your application).

The `connected` attribute should be in the third model, which will join the two others. To start with, generate the corresponding migration with the command: `rails g model AccountConnection account:belongs_to main_account:belongs_to connected:boolean`. This command will result in:

```
class CreateAccountConnections < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :account_connections do |t|
      t.belongs_to :account, foreign_key: true
      t.belongs_to :main_account, foreign_key: true
      t.boolean :connected

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The `AccountConnection` model will also be created. Then you just need to set the correct associations:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :account_connections
   has_many :main_accounts, through: :account_connections
end
```

```
class MainAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :account_connections
   has_many :accounts, through: :account_connections
end
```

```
class AccountConnection < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :account
   belongs_to :main_account
end
```

As for the link between the models:

```
account = Account.first # this could be any Account instance
main_account = MainAccount.first # this could also be any MainAccount instance
connection = account.account_connections.create(main_account: main_account, connected: true)
# or the other way around:
connection2 = main_account.account_connections.create(account: account, connected: true)
```

Comment: gotcha. thanks so much. applied this solution and worked like a charm!